# Verbal Job Offer -Delays/Backlogs on Processing of Offers

Tags: hiring, process

I was interviewed on 29th of Jan 2016.

A week after on 8th of Jan 2016 to be exact, I followed up for the result.The hiring manager called me and told me they are offering me the job and that if I submit the reuirements he will send me the offer by Fri of the same week which was 12th Feb 2016.I submitted everything straightaway and answered all medical questionnares online. I didnt received any offer on that Friday 12 Feb 2016.

Monday I followed up....He called me...the delay was due to the manager on leave...The following Friday 26 of Feb 2016 - He called my referees...'Was really slow but I am willing to wait...

29th of Feb I followed up again - I was told there were backlogs on job offers due to them being really being very busy at the HR Department and that he is aiming this Friday 4th of March 2016. He has also sent me a link to an online course aponsored by the company - I need to have the 'white card' when I start the job....But no written offer yet...I will do as I am told no problems...But I am really getting frustrated and anxious...

This is a very large company and the second biggest in their industry in Australia.
What should I do? The company is a consortium between/of two large companies.

Their HR manager are very accomodating and helpful.

What should I do please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Be patient.  I expect all you have been told is the truth and I suspect the hiring manager is also frustrated.  It's a fact, people do take vacations in the summer!  It's very difficult finding a good person for any job; the manager looked, interviewed, verified references, and you've been found.  They don't want to lose you and clearly want to hire you and get you working to meet their needs.  A couple of weeks is like a whiff of time in the big corporate world.  And, frankly, it's much easier to just say "you're not hired" rather than disingenuously lead on a promising candidate.